# Looking for novel with female character whose eyes change color when pregnant?

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book involved some kind of prophecy around a woman with a certain eye color, and the female character was an alien who didn't know much about her species so she didn't know her eye color would change when she became pregnant. She fell in love with the male character and the prophecy was about her all along.

I read it sometime around 1999, and it was mostly a romance in a scifi/fantasy setting. I didn't buy it myself, it was in my dorm's common room in Australia, so I can't remember the title!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall anything about the cover of the book?